# Windows Short name does not match long name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am copying a list of files using a prefix (i.e., ABCD*) to match files in a batch script. However, some files that appear to match are being left behind while other files that don't match are getting grabbed.

I ran a dir /X and found that the shortname for a handful of the files didn't match their longname:

```
4/17/2015  02:04 PM   554  ABCDEF~1.TXT     abcdefghijklmnopqrs.txt
4/17/2015  02:08 PM   123  ABCDEF~2.TXT     1234567890.txt
4/17/2015  03:18 PM   233  987654~1.TXT     abcdefg123456.txt
```

Any idea why something like this might happen and how to resolve it?

Comment: To hopefully clarify, the data above is just an example. The files are coming in from an external source and are then moved into specific directories based upon the first 4 characters of their filename. The script that is does this won't have the opportunity to rename the files' shortnames. If the script can only use the longname (instead of both the long and short names) that would be ideal.

Comment: Please edit a real example into your question and reveal what you actually want to do. A `copy ABCD*` matches either long or shortname; on the artifical example you've constructed, the first and third would be copied, but for the second, `abcd*`  doesn't match either name.

Comment: In my limited testing, `DIR` and `COPY` match wildcards on long file names and the 8.3 names. So, in the sample data above, for `ABCD*`, all three files would be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sample data is representative of your actual files, you could specify `ABCDEFG*` to workaround this issue.

**EDIT**

Since the above suggestion is not an option, you could use `FSUTIL` to remove all of the 8.3 names.

This command will analyze the files in the current directory (`.`) and display the changes without actually making them.

```
fsutil 8dot3name strip /t .
```

Remove the `/t` parameter to actually remove the 8.3 names.

You can also run:

```
fsutil 8dot3name strip
```

to see all of the options.

Comment: This is the best choice for my situation because the strip can be executed before the move. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Short and long file names are not required to match. The default algoritm is documented [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) under *"How NTFS Generates Short File Names"*. You can also find it in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

You can change the short file name with

```
fsutil file setshortname longFileName shortFileName
```